# Rails logger logging to console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I am using Rails logger to log information in my Rails 4 application. 
I do not set `config.logger=Logger.new(STDOUT)` in my configuration and just keep the default option for logger.However, besides the log file under `/log` folder, the information is still printed to the console when the statement `Rails.logger.info` is used.

Why does this happen as I only want the log info to be inside the log file, not printed to console? Thanks

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this happens in a development environment only. Do you really want to suppress logging to the console in `dev`?

Comment: Oh I dont know that this only happens in development environment. This helps explain a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how `rails s` behaves. It puts the logs in `log/development.log` as well as show at the command line. As thats more convenient for most cases.

Anyways if you do not want it you can run your server something like this:

```
rails s 1> /dev/null
```

This would redirect all that text to /dev/null

Comment: `1` in `1>` is redundant. Also, rails logger might be configured to avoid printing anything to console; doing that printing, even followed by redirection to `/dev/null`, slows things down and should not be used.

Answer (score -1):

If you only wants to print the log in log/development.log and not in the console, then use below to start your `rails server`.

```
rails s > log/development.log
```

Comment: This is “how to screw rails up” advice. Don’t you think that redirecting the output to the _already opened by rails for writing file_ is not the best idea?

Comment: @mudasobwa: He don't want to print the log in the console, so the above will work as per the question

Comment: @mudasobwa: I have executed above & I am not able to see the logs in console. All the logs are going on log/development.log file.